# Bootstrap 4 vertical carousel not working in Bootstrap 5 beta

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was building vertical Carousel with Codeply's example, which works flawlessly with latest `Bootstrap 4.6`. But when the same Vertical Carousel was tried with `Bootstrap 5 beta` the carousel example was not working.

Original [codyply-vertical-carousel-example](https://www.codeply.com/p/JxZ8htyOFN)

[Modified forked version](https://www.codeply.com/p/2SoD9GiGPv)  tested to work flawlessly with `Bootstrap 4.6` latest version.

However, the same example is not working with `Bootstrap 5 beta` .  [The bootstrap 5 version](https://www.codeply.com/p/LOGccJsJ24)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

**Edit :** To make it simple scroll(slide), just sliding the below cards/items, remove the `slide` class. It will simply have the `clickable` sliding cards

**Bonus** If anyone could provide sliding animation, default animation(with `slide` class) show **n** items in between animation after `click`

Comment: **Bootstrap 5 Migration Guide:** _https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/_

Comment: @Manas Did you find any change of class in Bootstrap 5 from Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different I have found in Carousel Bootstrap 5 beta:

1. In Carousel controls it is `data-bs-slide` not `data-slide`
2. When click on **next** arrow added class in carousel item is `carousel-item-start` not `carousel-item-left`
   and When click on **previous** arrow added class in carousel item is `carousel-item-end` not `carousel-item-right`

[Example link](https://jsfiddle.net/cnx26ega/1/)

Comment: That's I think missing the basic `Bootstrap 5` classes. thanks though

Comment: This could be another question though, but still - do you know how to change the animation style. From 3-4 transition, it should show least amount of image/items. Just simpled transition

Comment: Which type of animation?

Comment: Not a big issue, but there is also a comma missing in the second block of classes, in the `transform` property after the `100%`.